# Step in the proof of the adjoint representation of the Lie bracket

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology, lie-groups, partial-derivative, lie-algebras

Let $a: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow M$ a differential map such that $a(s, 0) = p$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow T_p M$ the path given by $\gamma(s) : = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}_{|t=0} a(s,t)$. We identify $T_{\gamma(0)}(T_pM) $ canonical with $T_pM$. The path $\gamma$ define a tangent vector $\gamma '(0) \in T_p M$. Let $\phi \in \mathcal{E}(p)$, where $\mathcal{E}(p)$ is the set of the function germ in $p$ . Show that
\begin{align}
\gamma '(0)(\phi) = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial s \partial t}_{|s=t=0} \phi(a(s, t))
\end{align}
Hint: wlog $(M, p ) = (\mathbb{R}^n , 0)$ and $\phi$ linear

I have no idea how to approach this exercise. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You were given a hint, which says that it suffices to show the statement is true for one special, simple case $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, $p=0$, and $\phi$ is linear.  Did you do that case?

Comment: I'm trying, but I have some problem already to understand the notation $\gamma'(0)(\phi)$. Should I consider $\gamma'(0)$ as left invariant vector field and then use the local coordinates to do the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have trouble understanding the notation $\gamma'(0)(\phi)$.  That's a good place to start.  Remember that elements of $T_pM$ act on $\mathcal{E}(p)$ like this: if $\gamma$ is a path in $M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, then $\gamma'(0) \in T_pM$.  If $\phi \in \mathcal{E}(p)$, the action is
$$
    \gamma'(0)(\phi) = \left.\frac{d}{ds}(\phi(\gamma(s)))\right|_{s=0}
$$
In your problem, $\gamma(s) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t} a(s,t)\right|_{t=0}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful!